# How to mount ISO under Windows 10 without 3rd party software?

Tags: windows-10, mount, iso-image

I heard, that under Windows 10 it is possible to mount DVD image without 3rd party software.

How to do that?

Manuals like below

[image]

do not work for me, since I don't have `Disc Image Tools / Manage` menu, and I don't have `Mount` command in context menu.

How to accomplish?

Comment: Windows has had a built ISO mount functionality since Windows 8, if you install third-party software, that functionality is disabled until the default file associatation is reset

Comment: Alternately, you can use default programs to reset ISO file associations, which would bring back the Mount option. [Burn Disk Image and Mount Missing in Context Menu for ISO or IMG Files](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/iso-img-burn-disk-image-mount-missing-right-click-menu/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entry is missing if you associated the ISO with a different tool. Press SHIFT Key and do a right click on an ISO file and select `Open with`.

[image]

Here select Explorer and set the option to open ISOs all the time with Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

If you previously installed software that remains associated with the **".ISO"** file type, you won't see the **Disc Image Tools** on the File Explorer ribbon and if you right-click an ISO file, you won't see the option to **Mount** the image within the Context Menu.  You need to restore the default ISO file type association to bring back those options:

1. Press <kbd>[image: WindowsKey]</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Within the search field type **Default Programs** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. In the subsequent Settings window scroll to the bottom and select **Set defaults by app**
   [image: Set Defaults by app]
4. When the window opens to Set Default Programs, on the left side scroll down to select **Windows Disc Image Burner** and on the right side select **Set this program as default**
   [image: Set Default Programs]
5. If you prefer to **Choose defaults for this program**, ensure that you check the box for the **.iso** file type and click the **Save** button
   [image: Set Program Associations]
6. Click the **OK** button
7. Close the **Default Programs** window
8. Reboot

Once the procedure is done, whenever you work with an ISO image file you should again see Disc Image Tools on the File Explorer ribbon and the option to Mount the image within the Context Menu.

([Source](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5507-default-apps-choose-windows-10-a.html))